# How to plot a sine wave with matplotlib from the matplotlib tutorial exercise

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Try to reproduce the figure shown in images/exercise_1-1.png

# Our data...
x = np.linspace(1, 10, 99)
y1, y2, y3 = np.cos(x), np.cos(x + 1), np.cos(x + 2)
names = ['Signal 1', 'Signal 2', 'Signal 3']
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot([x], [y1], color='lightblue', linewidth=3)
plt.show()
```

I've tried every possible way but it won't show. Anyone got a tip?

Output:

[image]

Comment: Don't put `x` and `y1` in a list like this: `[x]`, etc. -- they're already iterable, so simply use `x`, `y1`.

Comment: ow yeah, ofcourse! Thanks, these small mistakes always cost me so much time :(